# Как сделать проверку на двойное нажатие мыши?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать проверку на двойное нажатие мыши в unity?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float doubleClickTime = .2f; // Временной порог для двойного нажатия
float lastClickTime; // Время последнего нажатия    

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        float timeSinceLastClick = Time.time - lastClickTime; // Вычисляем время, прошедшее с последнего нажатия

        //Выводим сообщение о клике
        if (timeSinceLastClick <= doubleClickTime)
            () => Debug.Log("Double click")();
        else
            () => Debug.Log("Normal click")();

    lastClickTime = Time.time; // Обновляем время последнего нажатия
    }
}
```